# MS SQL SERVER 2008r2 connection with Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source=BIMESH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=LibrSystem;integrated security=true");
```

In this code the escape sequence is not acceptable.
  please rectify this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try either

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data source=BIMESH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=LibrSystem;integrated security=true");
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source=BIMESH-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=LibrSystem;integrated security=true");
```

[You should have a look at verbatim string literals, and escaped string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: you can try  this also: `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(); con.connectionstring = @"Data source=BIMESH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=LibrSystem;integrated security=true";`